# Playing .WAV file on Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, html5-audio, filestream

I am trying to play a .WAV file on Internet Explorer thru windows media player ( assuming that is the default media player for the client machine )

**View**

```
 <a class="" href="@Url.Action("VoiceSample", "Report", new { Num = item.Num })">Play Voice</a>
```

**Report Controller**

```
    public FileStreamResult VoiceSample(string Num)
    {
        FileStream fs = null;
        string sFileName = "";            
        string fnameWithFullPath = @"C:\TEST.wav";

        FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo(fnameWithFullPath);
        if (myFile.Exists)
        {                

            fs = new FileStream(fnameWithFullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            sFileName = "TEST.wav";
        }           

        return File(fs, "audio/x-wav");
    }
```

**This works** perfectly when I run from the **localhost**, but it **doesn't when I publish the code to server and run from the server**, the windows media player opens up and throws the below error:-

"Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file."

But again it works if I return with file name also as below, but then the Internet Explorer will prompt with Open/Save... options. I just want it to play as soon as I click on the link "Play Voice", don't want the IE prompt.

```
   return File(fs, "audio/x-wav",sFileName );
```

What has to be done differently to get it played when its been running from server?

Just noticed , the network tab on on Dev Toolbar (F12) I see the all the Header responses are same except X-SourceFiles was not there when it ran from the server.I think which is okay since it happens when run from localhost.

Appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that it runs into the protection for "File has been downloaded from the internet and thus might not be save" situation, with a slighly faulty exception message. There is nothing really you can do here. And I feel like you are on the totally wrong track to play a audiofile from inside the Browser. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that, that no other approach can do?

Comment: Exactly I want to play an audio file with in the browser: HTML 5 <audio> will do the job elegantly in all browsers except in Internet Explorer ( .wav files won't play in Internet Explorer ), So I detect the browser and want to the audio in Media player. You can see what happens the .wav file on this link  http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/index-e.html

Comment: Only thing is instead a direct link to .wav file,I will be passing the audio stream... Not sure why it doesn't work from code which is published on a windows 2008 server and IIS 7.5

Comment: Users are supposed to be using Edge. The Internet Explorer line is effectively deprecated. Edge has a number of changes, including no more support for ActiveX execution. As long as it runs in Edge as in every other HTML 5 browser, I would consider your job done. And if it does not run in Edge, then I consider that plain a bug in Edge. Working around it would be wrong - the browser has to conform to the standart. Jumping through those kinds of hoops is exactly what HTML 5 tried to avoid. And User Agent ID is easuly spoofed too.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, 4% of the internet population still use IE. And that is a huge number, we can't ignore those uses or force to update to Windows 10/Edge. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Have you checked that the (production) server returns correct mime-type when sending the file (in the response)?